# Using Remote Objects in JavaScript to query parent Object field

Tags: visualforce, remote-objects

I am using remoting on VF page. Here is the code snippet.

```
<apex:remoteObjects >
    <apex:remoteObjectModel jsShortHand="sfNode" name="SBQQ__QuoteLine__c" fields="Id,Name,SBQQ__Quote__c,SBQQ__Quote__r.Name,SBQQ__ListPrice__c,SBQQ__Quantity__c">
        <apex:remoteObjectField name="SBQQ__RequiredBy__c" jsShorthand="Parent" />
    </apex:remoteObjectModel>
</apex:remoteObjects>
```

The above piece of code throws an error that "SBQQ__Quote__r.Name"
such relation doesn't exist.
But when I do a query in workbench it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation doesn't state any particular limitation, but it appears that you cannot query parent or child records. Instead, you'll need to retrieve them separately:

```
<apex:remoteObjects >
    <apex:remoteObjectModel name="SBQQ__QuoteLine__c" fields="Id,Name,SBQQ__Quote__c,SBQQ__RequiredBy__c,SBQQ__ListPrice__c,SBQQ__Quantity__c">
    <apex:remoteObjectModel name="SBQQ__Quote__c" fields="Id,Name" />
</apex:remoteObjects>
```

At that point, you'll need the query the quote lines, and then query the quote.